# Can someone explain the ^= operator to me?

Tags: python

I've been searching and found that the ^= operator is the same as running the function ixor(a,b,). However this returns the sum of a and b, so then how is ^= different than +=?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `1 + 1` and `1 ^ 1`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Bitwise_operation

Comment: Also try `set(range(1,3)) ^ set(range(2,4))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The carat `^` is bitwise XOR. Imagine it like this:

```
>>> 8^3
11
```

---

```
8 in binary: 1000
3 in binary: 0011
8^3:         1011
```

Comment: Great, clear explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
x ^ y
```

Does a **[bitwise exclusive or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398427/what-does-bitwise-xor-exclusive-or-mean)**. Each bit of the output is the same as the corresponding bit in x if that bit in y is 0, and it's the complement of the bit in x if that bit in y is 1.
[source](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators)